# Android Studio 4.0 shortcuts changed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

This week I updated to Android Studio 4.0, and one of the first things I noticed was that some of my favorite shortcuts like CMD+W has changed to CMD+F4 (which the touchbar wont actually show the F keys anymore), and also CMD+O changed to CMD+N.  Is there any way to get them back to what they were to set to in Android Studio 3?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It happened to me too after upgrading to Android Studio 4.0, it was fixed after I went to Android Studio > Preferences > Keymap then choice MacOS:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. I installed the 4.0 version, then my shortcuts go all crazy. Fixed it with your help. Thanks again.

Comment: this answer is way better than deleting the other file. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

**Fixed**, it happen because Android Studio 4.0 by default use Intellij Keymap, fixed by change back to MacOs keymap. **Android Studio > Preferences > Keymap > macOS**

[image]

Answer (score 19):

For Mac users:

I went to:

`~/Library/Preferences/Android Studio 4.0/options`

and deleted `keymap.xml`, which I noticed was not present on the previous version folder.

It seems to have the shortcuts working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

Go to this location :

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\.AndroidStudio3.0\config\keymaps
```

And copy the file present inside that (Usually `Default Proper Redo.xml`) and paste it inside

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\keymaps
```

It will bring back all old shortcuts or alternatively

**Method 2:**

go to settings and search for keymap this window will come up

[image]

and search for the keystroke you want or navigate around those

[image]

Right-click on the shortcut you want to change and a window will come up just press the new keystroke that you want to assign

[image]

If the same keystroke is applied to some other actions it will show a dailog just confirm it by removing old keystrokes ...

You can relate to MacOS ...

Answer (score 0):

To open the keymap settings, choose File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences) and navigate to the Keymap pane.

Select the short cut you want to modify then add/assign new keys to short cut.

[See for more info](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS you can use :
"macOS Keymap" plugin by JetBrains

Restart IDE then select macOS in Keymap preferences